# 'extends' from TypeScript does not the same job as constraint on generics in C#

Tags: typescript, generics

on "this" in the following TypeScript code I get the following error:

Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  Type 'MyClass' is not assignable to type 'T'.ts(2345)

written in TypeScript 3.2.2 (in Angular 7)

```
export abstract class MyClass<T extends MyClass<T>> {

    childList: T[];

    foo = () => {
            const index = this.childList.indexOf(this);
            // ...
    }
}
```

This is how I would write it in C#:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> where T : MyClass<T>
{
    public T[] childList { get; set; }

    public void foo()
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(childList, this);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any feedback !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the C#, but in TypeScript you are declaring that `T extends MyClass<T>`, which means that `T` is a *subtype* of `MyClass<T>`, not *identical to* `MyClass<T>`.  So any value of type `T` can be assigned to a variable of type `MyClass<T>`, but not vice versa.

The [type definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1284) of `Array<X>.indexOf(y)` expects `y` to be assignable to `X`, not vice versa.  So it is an error to call `Array<T>.indexOf()` on a parameter of type `MyClass<T>`.  One way to address this is to declare `childList` to be of type `Array<MyClass<T>>` instead of `Array<T>`:

```
  childList!: MyClass<T>[];
```

But for all I know that would show up as an issue somewhere else, because at some point you will want to assume that `T` is identical to `MyClass<T>`, and it just isn't the case.  You can always fix things with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), but I think that you might want a completely different solution here: [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types).

Instead of trying to represent a circular/recursive type like `Foo<T extends Foo<T>>` and chasing your own tail, use the type `this` to represent "the type of the current class".  Your `MyClass` becomes:

```
export abstract class MyClass {

  childList!: this[];

  foo() {
    const index = this.childList.indexOf(this); // okay
  }
}
```

And subclasses more or less work the way you expect:

```
export class MyConcreteClass extends MyClass {
  bar() {
    this.childList.indexOf(this); // still works
  }
}
```

And instances cash out `this` into the actual type of the instance:

```
const y = new MyConcreteClass();
y.childList; // type MyConcreteClass[];
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot ! This cleared up things for me !
I'll go for type assertion as I have to stick to my model for reusability.